# How to require files by default without mentioning explicitly

Tags: ruby

I defined a custom instance method in the `String` class that I want to use in my other ruby files. I can do it by `require`-ing the file (that I defined my custom method in), but I want to use it naturally (without having to `require`).

For example: I defined this in my 'custom_string.rb' file:

```
class String
  def set_style(style)
    puts "\n#{self}"
    self.size.times do
    print style
    end
  end
end
```

Then, to use my `set_style` method in my 'test.rb' file, I have to do this:

```
require 'custom_string'
puts "hello".set_style("*")
```

I'm not using a Rails project. Is there a way to include my file into ruby by default (from the ruby command line) so it is available to all files in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 1.9 help:

```
$ ruby --help
Usage: ruby [switches] [--] [programfile] [arguments]
  -0[octal]       specify record separator (\0, if no argument)
  -a              autosplit mode with -n or -p (splits $_ into $F)
  -c              check syntax only
  -Cdirectory     cd to directory, before executing your script
  -d              set debugging flags (set $DEBUG to true)
  -e 'command'    one line of script. Several -e's allowed. Omit [programfile]
  -Eex[:in]       specify the default external and internal character encodings
  -Fpattern       split() pattern for autosplit (-a)
  -i[extension]   edit ARGV files in place (make backup if extension supplied)
  -Idirectory     specify $LOAD_PATH directory (may be used more than once)
  -l              enable line ending processing
  -n              assume 'while gets(); ... end' loop around your script
  -p              assume loop like -n but print line also like sed
  -rlibrary       require the library, before executing your script
  -s              enable some switch parsing for switches after script name
  -S              look for the script using PATH environment variable
  -T[level=1]     turn on tainting checks
  -v              print version number, then turn on verbose mode
  -w              turn warnings on for your script
  -W[level=2]     set warning level; 0=silence, 1=medium, 2=verbose
  -x[directory]   strip off text before #!ruby line and perhaps cd to directory
  --copyright     print the copyright
  --version       print the version
```

Take a look on:

```
-rlibrary       require the library, before executing your script
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants. If the OP didn't mind typing `-rlibrary ...` each time, then the OP would not have asked such question.

Comment: This answer per se is not a full answer to the question, but if you suggest defining a terminal command to invoke that, then that might be a full answer.

Comment: Much appreciate the answer and all of your comments and discussions. 
As much as I'd the functionality, I think this is the safest way of achieving what I wanted. It works fine in command-line(I don't mind typing a flag each time), and even in an IDE, such as RubyMine for example, I have the option to configure my console by adding the flag into the 'Ruby Arguments' field.
So from overall perspective, I liked the answer very much and thanks a lot to Hauleth.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not `require 'custom_string'` but found away for this to be automatically included, what happens when you run your program at another location, different server, share the code on github etc. The code would no longer execute as expected. The results that you post when asking for help would no longer match up with other peoples. This sounds like a bad idea to change Ruby behaviour in an untraceable manor.

If you just want `irb` to have this behaviour then you can add the require to your `~/.irbrc`.

@Hauleth solution of adding it the command line allows the change of behaviour to be traced. An alias can be added to `.bashrc` or other shell rc to give this behaviour by default.

Comment: I don't think it matters for the OP whether it is traced. The OP seems to just want to save typing.

Comment: Would that not lead to hard to find issues later on?

Comment: @Munkymorgy Great point!! much appreciate your advice and answer. Thanks very much.